# Minimum total capacity cut

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

In the network below, the numbers indicate capacities of the edges. It is a network flow problem. The question asks for the `minimum total capacity cut`. My lecturer's answer, shown in the image with a red jiggly line, is:

```
The minimum total capacity cut contains arcs {AB, SC, SE} as shown.
```

My answer is `{SA, SC, EF}`. I'm basically doing the same, only I avoid edge `SA` and use `EF` rather than `AB`. Why am I wrong?

[image: network]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the flow can still pass through S->E->C->D->T so your set of edges is not even a cut.

A cut is a set of edges that once removes makes it impossible for flow to happen from S to T.

Do keep in mind that removing edges does not remove the vertices themselves.

Here's an easy way to get minimum cut:

- Run any max flow algorithm on residual graph (Ford-Fulkerson, Edmonds
  Karp, Dinic, etc)
- Do BFS from source node ignoring saturated edges
  (edges where flow value = edge capacity)
- Now take all edges that go
  from visited nodes to unvisited nodes
- Those edges will be one of possible min cuts

Comment: Ah, yeah. Is there an algorithm for this or is it by random inspection?

Comment: @s5s added an algorithm to answer that explains how to get min cut